# How can I force the Eclipse toolbar to be on one row

Tags: eclipse

The toolbar seems to like to take 2 rows instead of one after a restart, even though:

- there is enough horizontal space;
- I manually arrange them to be on one row;
- the toolbars are locked.

[Eclipse toolbar http://img73.imageshack.us/img73/4266/eclipsetoolbar.png](http://img73.imageshack.us/img73/4266/eclipsetoolbar.png)

How can I prevent the toolbar position from being reset after a restart?

---

This is Eclipse 3.5.1 on Linux x86 GTK.

*Update*: Please note that Eclipse saves the workspace - my toolbar customisations work - except for the 'please please remain on one row' setting.

Comment: Just added some bug links. Looks like your bug report n° 292398 is a duplicate of... bug 69616 (2004)

Answer (score 2):

If eclipse does not successfully save its perspective, that may be due to:

- a right issue (read-only files in the workspace? Wrong user for launching the eclipse process)
- a starting issue (option --clean deep within an eclipse.ini; consider [replacing it with this eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590))

---

Regarding the toolbar layout specifically, this problem has been seen before, and before you reported it in [bug 292398](https://bugs.eclipse.org/292398), you can actually read:

- [bug 52229](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=52229): Toolbar layout not retained across sessions, possibly related to:
- [bug 62411](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=62411): ApplicationWindow's CoolBar does not re-layout window's contents on CoolItem's drag, which leads to:
- [bug 203370](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=203370): mentions "There are some other outstanding bugs in ToolBar."

... which says it all.

When I said "this problem has been seen before", meet [bug 69616](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=69616), reported 2004-07-08 for eclipse3.0.
Still pending.

> > I unlock the toolbars and set their positions. but they are always back all
> >     tossed in the left on eclipse start.
>
> Yes, the cool item ordering will be remembered, but the absolute positions will not.

Comment: Eclipse saves the workspace - my toolbar customisations work - _except_ for the 'please please remain on one row' setting.

Comment: Coolbar? _the cool item ordering will be remembered,_ ? This stuff is priceless. Now I know why Mozilla used AwesomeBar - cool was taken. I'm going to invent my own GroovyBar soon.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to prevent toolbar elements to change position, but I find a way to reset it. 
You could reset a workbench with toolbar (I didn't find a way to reset tollbar only). You could do it by removing file: workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi

Answer (score 0):

Try Window->Save Perspective As and save with the same as you use.
It think, this will be enough.

Comment: Hm... Do you try to look through https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/ ?
May be this is bug?